# Yocto Systemd Configuration

Tags: yocto, systemd, bitbake, nxp-microcontroller

I am trying to start a service on boot, however I am having issues building.
This is my tree structure in my custom layer

```
michael@michael-VirtualBox:~/Documents/simple_daemon/sources/meta-simpledaemon$ tree
.
├── conf
│   └── layer.conf
├── COPYING.MIT
├── README
└── recipes-example
    ├── example
    │   └── example_0.1.bb
    └── simpledaemon
        ├── files
        │   └── simpledaemon.service
        └── simpledaemon_git.bb
```

In my local.conf I have added the following to the end:

```
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " bbexample "
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " simpledaemon "
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " packagegroup-core-ssh-openssh "
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " openssh-sftp-server "


DISTRO_FEATURES_append = " systemd"
VIRTUAL-RUNTIME_init_manager = " systemd"
DISTRO_FEATURES_BACKFILL_CONSIDERED = "sysvinit"
VIRTUAL-RUNTIME_initscripts = ""
```

My `.bb` file is as follows:

```
# Recipe created by recipetool
# This is the basis of a recipe and may need further editing in order to be fully functional.
# (Feel free to remove these comments when editing.)

# WARNING: the following LICENSE and LIC_FILES_CHKSUM values are best guesses - it is
# your responsibility to verify that the values are complete and correct.
LICENSE = "MIT"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://LICENSE;md5=ca119cf6dcda0f0883a416a3e7f94cc2"

SRC_URI = "git://github.com/MichaelBMiner/simpledaemon;protocol=https"

# Modify these as desired
PV = "1.0+git${SRCPV}"
SRCREV = "a37a89df4d53bca97c12c8908cbe8552032417b4"

inherit systemd

S = "${WORKDIR}/git"

SYSTEMD_SERVICE_${PN} = "simpledaemon.service"
do_compile () {
    ${CC} ${LDFLAGS} simpledaemon.c -o simpledaemon
}
do_install () {
    install -d ${D}${bindir}
    install -m 0755 ${WORKDIR}/simpledaemon ${D}${bindir}
    install -d ${D}${systemd_unitdir}/system
    install -m 0644 ${WORKDIR}/simpledaemon.service ${D}${systemd_unitdir}/system sed -i -e     's,@BINDIR@,${bindir},g' ${D}${systemd_unitdir}/system/simpledaemon.service
}

# NOTE: if this software is not capable of being built in a separate build directory
# from the source, you should replace autotools with autotools-brokensep in the
# inherit line
inherit autotools

# Specify any options you want to pass to the configure script using EXTRA_OECONF:
EXTRA_OECONF = ""
```

My simpledaemon.service is as follows:

```
[Unit]
Description=Example service
[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=@BINDIR@/simple-service
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I got all of this information from the book Embedded Linux Development Using Yocto Project Cookbook Second Edition.

All of my builds have been successful until I attempt to add this new service. This book makes no mention of an init shell script for systemd services. I am also pulling code from GitHub rather than code in my build directory (you can look at the repo).

When I run `bitbake` I am given the error `Didn't find service unit 'simpledaemon.service', specified in SYSTEMD_SERVICE_simpledaemon.`. This tells me it is a path error that I can only assume arises from my GitHub structure. Can anyone shine some light on this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a few issues with your recipe that lead to your error:

##### 1. Use correct `SRCREV`:

> ```py
> SRCREV = "a37a89df4d53bca97c12c8908cbe8552032417b4"
> ```

The `SRCREV` above refers to a commit in your repository before the `.service` file was added. Change this to the latest commit, `2140a0646b3ffc6595c50ac549dc6f1220f66c28`

##### 2. Remove steps already described by autotools:

Since your source code uses autotools and your Yocto recipe inherits the autotools class, Yocto will automatically run the equivalent of `./configure`, `make`, `make install` to configure/compile/install this package.

Therefore, you can remove your entire `do_compile` task and the first few lines of `do_install` where you manually install the binary:

> ```sh
> do_compile () {
>     ${CC} ${LDFLAGS} simpledaemon.c -o simpledaemon
> }
>
> do_install () {
>     install -d ${D}${bindir}
>     install -m 0755 ${WORKDIR}/simpledaemon ${D}${bindir}
> ```

##### 3. Use `do_install_append` to install the systemd service

The `inherit autotools` at the end of your recipe file causes your `do_install` task to be overridden as the autotools class sets it to an autotools-style method.

Since you need the autotools `do_install` to run, and also some of your own code (to install the systemd service), you can move the inherit upward and combine it with the systemd one:

```sh
inherit autotools systemd
```

and, then define a `do_install_append` function to append on the extra steps required to install your systemd service:

```sh
do_install_append () {
    install -d ${D}${systemd_system_unitdir}
    install -m 0644 ${S}/simpledaemon.service ${D}${systemd_system_unitdir}
    sed -i -e 's,@BINDIR@,${bindir},g' ${D}${systemd_system_unitdir}/simpledaemon.service
}
```

There were a number of errors in your original `do_install` too:

1. The `simpledaemon.service` file is installed from `${S}` which is the source directory (i.e the git directory), not `${WORKDIR}`
2. The `sed` command should be on a new line
3. (optimisation) You can use `${systemd_system_unitdir}` in place of `${systemd_unitdir}/system`

##### 4. Remove unused `EXTRA_OECONF = ""`

Setting `EXTRA_OECONF` to empty will override any default value it had, which often is defined by the Yocto distro. If you do need extra arguments to `./configure` consider using [`PACKAGECONFIG`](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/ref-manual/variables.html#term-PACKAGECONFIG) or at last resort `EXTRA_OECONF += "--foo-bar"`.

---

##### Complete recipe:

```sh
LICENSE = "MIT"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://LICENSE;md5=ca119cf6dcda0f0883a416a3e7f94cc2"

SRC_URI = "git://github.com/MichaelBMiner/simpledaemon;protocol=https"

PV = "1.0+git${SRCPV}"
SRCREV = "2140a0646b3ffc6595c50ac549dc6f1220f66c28"

inherit systemd autotools

S = "${WORKDIR}/git"

SYSTEMD_SERVICE_${PN} = "simpledaemon.service"

do_install_append () {
    install -d ${D}${systemd_system_unitdir}
    install -m 0644 ${S}/simpledaemon.service ${D}${systemd_system_unitdir}
    sed -i -e 's,@BINDIR@,${bindir},g' ${D}${systemd_system_unitdir}/simpledaemon.service
}
```

---

##### Debugging tip

A useful way to debug recipes is to dump the output of the following command to a file and inspect it:

```sh
bitbake -e your-recipe-or-image-name
```

If you inspect the output of `bitbake -e simpledaemon` for your original recipe, and look for the final definition of `do_install` (search for a line beginning with `do_install`). It was clear that after parsing, the function did not contain your steps to install the service code.

You can read more about this technique in the manual, under [Viewing Variable Values](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/dev-manual/common-tasks.html#viewing-variable-values).

Comment: This is some amazing advice! I will be trying this out this afternoon.

Comment: I did as you suggested and I am building my image now. I expect it to be done shortly. Do you know of any resources that would show how to use a private GitLab/GitHub repo?

Comment: Underneath, Yocto runs the same `git clone ...` command that you would run manually, so as long as you've got your SSH keys set up correctly on your user account, you should not have any trouble fetching from private git repos. You'll just need to ensure the `SRC_URI` specifies that Yocto should use SSH to fetch,  e.g. `SRC_URI = "git://git@github.com/username/project.git;protocol=ssh;branch=master"`

Answer (score 0):

can you move `simpledaemon` dir inside the example `dir`?

You can use [obmc-op-control-host_git.bb](https://github.com/openbmc/openbmc/tree/master/meta-phosphor/recipes-phosphor/host) as a reference.